# New User limitations

Tags: support, new-users

How long does it take to NOT be considered a 'New User'. Is it reputation, day/hour based?

Answer (score 11):

None of these answers are really correct. There are special limitations for Rep 1 users.

See

[What are the limits and restrictions for new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/document-rep-limit-for-new-users)

> New user (less than 15 rep) restrictions:
>
> - new users may not post images
> - new users may only post one URL
>
> New user (less than 100 rep) restrictions:
>
> - new users may only post one question every 20 minutes
> - new users may only post one answer every 2 minutes
>
> To lift these restrictions, gain more rep!

Comment: Just a suggestion, but perhaps these could be included in the FAQ under "What is reputation?" When I first started, I carefully looked up all the URLs in a reply - then found I couldn't post it. Having this in the FAQ would have decreased my frustration.

Comment: In addition to this, [new users (less than 15 rep) cannot mark their questions as community wiki when they initially ask them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49745/why-cant-i-mark-a-question-as-community-wiki-on-so-when-asking-it/49748#49748).

Comment: I'm wondering if it is less than 100 rep or less than or equal to 100 rep?  I just tried to post two questions in row and was informed I am a new user (pretty accurate :D ) and have to wait 20 minutes. I have exactly 100 rep.

Answer (score 4):

It is reputation based.  See ["What is reputation?" in the faq](https://superuser.com/faq).

> Amass enough reputation points and
> Super User will allow you to go beyond
> simply asking and answering questions:
>
> 15  Vote up
> 15  Flag offensive
> 50  Leave comments
> 100  Vote down (costs 1 rep), create new tags
> 200  Reduced advertising
> 250  Vote to close or open your questions
> 500  Retag questions
> 750  Edit community wiki posts
> 2000  Edit other people's posts
> 3000  Vote to close any questions
> 10000  Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
>
> At the high end of this
> reputation spectrum there is little
> difference between users with high
> reputation and moderators. That is
> very much intentional. We don't run
> Super User. The community does.

Answer (score 3):

The limit goes away once you hit [100 reputation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/)

Answer (score 1):

Reputation, I believe. I had that limit this morning (1 question per 20 minutes) and it went away as my reputation increased.

Comment: @Jonathan, this is hilarious now that you have 18k rep (and yes, I know this comment will eventually itself be dated).

Answer (score -1):

I'm still a "new user" and I've been using this site for seven months. Essentially, you're a new user until a bunch of people get together and decided to vote you up. I know... It really has nothing to do with *new*, but [like most bugs no one seems to care to fix it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48782/another-bundle-of-bug-reports-for-so)

Comment: Evan, your account is very unusual. For 99.999% of accounts this is not an issue.

Comment: @Jeff s/your account is/you are

Comment: @Evan ... I proclaim that, You are *special*.

Comment: @Jeff I propose a new three diamond user type just for @Evan

Comment: @Earlz: why? You would get one too.